# How to make the macOS standard Open/Save sheet search in current directory by default

Tags: macos, finder

By default, Finder performs searches in the This Mac, but I want it to perform them in the current directory. I changed this setting in *Finder Preferences > Advanced > When performing a search > Search the Current Folder*. Now it works when I search something specifically in Finder, but when I do it in the window that pops up when uploading online a file, or just when opening a file in some application, the search is still performed in This Mac. How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: This might perhaps be better re-worded. Finder is already doing what it's been told… it's just that other apps aren't ;) There is potentially an alternative method, if you drag the relevant file from Finder to the dialog, it will auto-populate.

Comment: @Tetsujin, sorry for my English :( It sounds really annoying to search the file in Finder separately and then drag it to the dialog; it's a lot more convenient to switch This Mac to Current directory each time, though I'd like to set this as a default...